# TSQL Subquery effeciency

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a subquery in a view to be returned as a column but I am not exactly sure what would give me the most efficient call.
I have View A that gathers a bunch of fields from different tables (one table being `Listings` that has has a 1 to many relationship with `OpenHours`) then one of the fields I want it to be from another table (`OpenHours`) that will only be Today's Open hours field.

The `OpenHours` table has `ListingID`, `Day` (0 based for the day of the week), Hours (text of the open hours such as "8:00am-5:00pm"). Here is what I need to do:

1. Check if `OpenTable` has a record for that particular listing that `day = 7`, if its 7 (which is not a day of the week) then return "Open 24 hours".
2. If does not exist then return the next record, since SQL Servers  `datepart(dw..` is 1 based, following will be used select `datepart(dw,getdate())-1` to get a 0 day based day of week starting on Sunday (Sunday being 0)
3. Return nothing if no records exist that match the criteria.

I would appreciate some help on this. I attempted to write this but could not get far. I am not sure how to declare variables for day of the week in the view.

**UPDATE**
here is my function, anyone see any glaring inefficiencies?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTodaysOpenHours](@ListingID int) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DayOfWeek int
--SQL Day of week starts on sunday but it is 1 based, listing open hours are 0 based
SET @DayOfWeek = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) - 1
DECLARE @OpenHours VARCHAR(50)
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM OpenHours WHERE Day = 7 AND ListingID = @ListingID) 
    SET @OpenHours = 'Open 24 Hours'
ELSE    
    SELECT @OpenHours  =  Hours FROM OpenHours WHERE ListingID = @ListingID AND Day = @DayOfWeek    

RETURN @OpenHours
END
```

**UPDATED VIEW**

```
ALTER view [dbo].[vListings]
as
SELECT  l.ListingID, l.ExpiryDate, l.IsApproved, l.IsActive,      l.Position,MoneyField1, DateField1, 
    IntField1, IntField2, IntField3, IntField4, 
    BoolField1, BoolField2, BoolField3,  
    OptionField1, OptionField2, OptionField3, OptionField4, 
    IsTop, TopStartDate, TopExpireDate, Address, Address + ' ' + c.Name + ' ' + p.Name AS FullAddress, 
    o1.Description as Options1Description,
    o2.Description as Options2Description,
    o3.Description as Options3Description,
    o4.Description as Options4Description, 
    COALESCE(
              (SELECT TOP 1 ThumbnailPath
               FROM Attachments
               WHERE ListingID = l.listingID), '/content/images/noImageThumbnail2.jpg') AS MainThumbnail,
               COALESCE(
              (SELECT TOP 1 ThumbnailPath2
               FROM Attachments
               WHERE ListingID = l.listingID), '/content/images/noImageThumbnail.jpg') AS MainThumbnail2,
    l.UserID,
    c.SubDomainName as CitySubDomainName, l.Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN l.IsAutoGenerated = 1  THEN l.ImportedPhoneNumber
        ELSE  dbo.FormatPhoneNumber(u.PhoneNumber)
    END as PhoneNumber,
    CASE 
        WHEN l.IsAutoGenerated = 1  THEN l.ImportedContactInfo
        ELSE  u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName
    END as ContractInfo,
    p.Abbv as StateAbbv,
    cn.Code as CountryCode,
    l.Comments, l.UniqueID, l.Rating, l.Website, 
    (select    L.ListingID,
isnull(H1.Hours, H2.Hours) as Hours
from Listings L
    outer apply (
        select Hours FROM OpenHours H WHERE H.Day = 7 
        AND H.ListingID = L.ListingID
    ) H1
     outer apply (
        select Hours FROM OpenHours H WHERE Day = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) - 1
        AND H.ListingID = L.ListingID
    ) H2
        --dbo.GetTodaysOpenHours(l.ListingID) as TodaysOpenHours


FROM Listings l
    INNER JOIN Cities c ON c.CityID = l.CITYID
    INNER JOIN Provinces p ON p.ProvinceID = c.ProvinceID
    INNER JOIN Countries cn ON cn.CountryID = p.CountryID
    INNER JOIN AspNetUsers u ON u.Id = l.UserID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Options1 o1 ON o1.OptionID = l.OptionField1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Options2 o2 ON o2.OptionID = l.OptionField2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Options3 o3 ON o3.OptionID = l.OptionField3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Options4 o4 ON o4.OptionID = l.OptionField4
```

GO

I get an error that says "incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM 
(FROM Listings l)

I upadted the view (added FROM) to the select statements as well

I prefer not to use t he function because I had to add an index to my openhours table on listingid and day in order to make it a little faster but if adding sql into view itself would be better that would be awesome

Comment: Do some queries, and check execution plans and statistics for the query. Then you can determine which route is the best in your given case. It might very well differ from situation to situation so the only way forth is to investigate.

Comment: You can't declare variables in a view. A view is not programming logic. If you really want some help here you need to provide some details.

Comment: updated the original with some code

Answer (score 0):

User defined function isn't usually the best performing solution. You could try just to add that SQL into the view / query by doing something like this (sorry, can't test this, hopefully there's no syntax errors):

```
select
    L.ListingID,
    isnull(H1.Hours, H2.Hours) as Hours
from Listing L
    outer apply (
        select Hours OpenHours H WHERE H.Day = 7 
        AND H.ListingID = L.ListingID
    ) H1
     outer apply (
        select Hours OpenHours H WHERE Day = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) - 1
        AND H.ListingID = L.ListingID
    ) H2
```

Comment: Updated the original post, I had to add FROM to ur select statements but still getting a syntax error, code for my view has been posted